# How to pass username as base 64 encoding format in header of web api swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have implemented a web api with basic authentication filter. When I want to call it from **Swagger**, I am facing below problems:

1) I am unable to pass the `username` in **Base64** encode.

2) `Username` is passed in Scheme property of `ActionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization` instead of Parameter property of the same.

I have tried with below code in swagger.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
 c.OperationFilter(() => new AddRequiredAuthorizationHeaderParameter());
 });

 public class AddRequiredAuthorizationHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            var filterPipeline = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
            var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                                    .Any(filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter);

            var allowAnonymous = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

            if (operation.parameters == null)
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "Authorization",
                @in = "header",
                type = "",
                required = true,
                description = "User Name"
            });
        }
    }
```

Please help me out.